# Getting 302 in ajax call in Symfony2.7 in PROD environment

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-302

I am using RHEL7 with all the required components.

Installed Symfony2.7 and getting 302 error for **PROD** environment in all the ajax calls on my Virtual Host setup. My conf file is having :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName newmaster.test.com
ServerAlias newmaster.test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/newmaster/test/web/
<Directory /var/www/html/newmaster/test/web/>
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            DirectoryIndex app.php

            # Various rewrite rules.
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                 RewriteEngine on
                 #Rewrite current-style URLs of the form 'index.php?q=x'.
                 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
            </IfModule>
</Directory>
SetEnv SYMFONY__WEBSITE newmaster
# The SYMFONY__ENVIRONMENT variable is optional, and will default to prod
SetEnv SYMFONY__ENVIRONMENT prod
ErrorLog "/etc/httpd/logs/test_newmaster_error.log"
CustomLog "/etc/httpd/logs/test_newmaster_access.log" combined
```

And web/.htaccess is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help!!!